# How install Real Time Application Interface (RTAI) in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, realtime

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to install rtai , my version kernel is : `3.16.0-30-generic`.

How to install the  Real Time Application Interface Rtai of kernel `3.16.0-30-generic`?

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
    sudo apt-get install rtai
```

and enter the root password. Rtai will then be installeld.